# Solving a non linear ODE based on a simplified vehicle along a path

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

I have made a simple model of a vehicle moving along a path $y(x)$.

The goal is to see how the vehicle behaves when a certain tractional force is applied along a path.

I have got the equation as such

$v(t)' = F_t - (g \sin(\beta (x)) +Av^2(t) +Bv(t) + C )$

$\beta(x) = \arctan(dy/dx)$

where $A$, $B$ and $C$ are constants related to friction and air drag. Normally I would develop a state equation system, but I don't think this works due to the non linear nature of the problem.

Any help is appreciated thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use MathJax to format your posts.